# Customize Bootstrap Table Pagination

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I am new at web development. I am currently using boostrap for my table pagination and it works perfectly. However, I want to customize it such as the buttons and where the search bar and filter will be placed. I am currently searching tutorials online but I haven't found any.

The question I have: Is it possible to customize it and if so, can you give me a tutorial or example?

Here is my **js file:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#executives').DataTable({
      "paging": "full",
      "bLengthChange": true,
      "bFilter": true,
      "iDisplayLength": 10
    });
  });
```

and here is my **HTML file:**

```
 <table id="executives">
            <thead>
            <tr id="myTable">
                <th>Customer Number</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```